# Atualizar todas dinamicas em uma planilha - erro

Tags: pivot

Peguei esse código em uma pergunta aqui, para atualizar as dinâmicas de uma planilha, porém ao rodar a macro, apresenta erro - `pt.RefreshTable`.

> Run-time error '1004': Reference isn't valid. (pt.RefreshTable)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

'Dimensionar variáveis
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet

'Atualiza Pivot Tables uma a uma
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.RefreshTable
            Next pt
        Next ws
```

Comment: Adicione à pergunta qual erro apareceu.

Comment: @Tony Run-time error '1004': Reference isn't valid. (pt.RefreshTable)